# How do I run a serverless batch job in Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, batch-processing, serverless, google-cloud-run

I have a batch job that takes a couple of hours to run. How can I run this in a serverless way on Google Cloud?

AppEngine, Cloud Functions, and Cloud Run are limited to 10-15 minutes. I don't want to rewrite my code in Apache Beam.

Is there an equivalent to AWS Batch on Google Cloud?

Comment: What is the framework of your model? What are the type of data? and where the data come from? What is your job kind?

Comment: @samuel liew why was the community answer deleted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally Google released (in Beta for the moment) Cloud Batch which does exactly what you want.
You push jobs (containers or scripts) and it runs. Simple as that.
https://cloud.google.com/batch/docs/get-started

Comment: Main complaint is that you can't run these off a scheduler/timer yet.

Answer (score 11):

Note: Cloud Run and Cloud Functions can now last up to 60 minutes.  The answer below remains a viable approach if you have a multi-hour job.

Vertex AI Training is serverless and long-lived. Wrap your batch processing code in a Docker container, push to gcr.io and then do:

```
gcloud ai custom-jobs create \
  --region=LOCATION \
  --display-name=JOB_NAME \
  --worker-pool-spec=machine-type=MACHINE_TYPE,replica-count=REPLICA_COUNT,executor-image-uri=EXECUTOR_IMAGE_URI,local-package-path=WORKING_DIRECTORY,script=SCRIPT_PATH
```

You can run any arbitrary Docker container — it doesn’t have to be a machine learning job. For details, see:

https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/training/create-custom-job#create_custom_job-gcloud

Today you can also use Cloud Batch: https://cloud.google.com/batch/docs/get-started#create-basic-job

Answer (score 4):

Google Cloud does not offer a comparable product to AWS Batch (see https://cloud.google.com/docs/compare/aws/#service_comparisons).

Instead you'll need to use Cloud Tasks or Pub/Sub to delegate the work to another product, such as Compute Engine, but this lacks the ability to do this in a "serverless" way.

Comment: google cloud batch job does it now (ie this answer is deprecated)

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same problem. in my case I went for:

1. Cloud Scheduler to start the job by pushing to Pub/Sub.
2. Pub/Sub triggers Cloud Functions.
3. Cloud Functions mounting a Compute Engine instance.
4. Compute Engine runs the batch workload and auto kills the instance
   once it’s done. You can read my post on medium:
   https://link.medium.com/1K3NsElGYZ

It might help you get started. There's also a follow up post showing how to use a Docker container inside the Compute Engine instance: https://medium.com/google-cloud/serverless-batch-workload-on-gcp-adding-docker-and-container-registry-to-the-mix-558f925e1de1

Answer (score 2):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58215421/6760372) to a [How to make GCE instance stop when its deployed container finishes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52748332/how-to-make-gce-instance-stop-when-its-deployed-container-finishes) will work for you as well:

In short:

- First dockerize your batch process.
- Then, create an instance:

  - Using a container-optmized image
  - And using a Startup script that pulls your docker image, runs it, and shutdown the machine at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Cloud Run. At the time of writing this, the timeout of Cloud Run (fully managed) is increased to 60 minutes, but in beta.

https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/request-timeout

> Important: Although Cloud Run (fully managed) has a maximum timeout of 60 minutes, only timeouts of 15 minutes or less are generally available: setting timeouts greater than 15 minutes is a Beta feature.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative for batch computing is using [Google Cloud Lifesciences](https://cloud.google.com/life-sciences).

An example application using Cloud Life Sciences is [dsub](https://github.com/DataBiosphere/dsub).

Or see the [Cloud Life Sciences Quickstart documentation](https://cloud.google.com/life-sciences/docs/quickstart).

Answer (score 0):

I found myself looking for a solution to this problem and built something similar to what mesmacosta has described in a different answer, in the form of a reusable tool called [gcp-runbatch](https://github.com/bitcomplete/gcp-runbatch).

If you can package your workload into a Docker image then you can run it using gcp-runbatch. When triggered, it will do the following:

1. Create a new VM
2. On VM startup, `docker run` the specified image
3. When the `docker run` exits, the VM will be deleted

Some features that are supported:

- Invoke batch workload from the command line, or deploy as a Cloud Function and invoke that way (e.g. to trigger batch workloads via Cloud Scheduler)
- stdout and stderr will be piped to Cloud Logging
- Environment variables can be specified by the invoker, or pulled from Secret Manager

Here's an example command line invocation:

```
$ gcp-runbatch \
  --project-id=long-octane-350517 \
  --zone=us-central1-a \
  --service-account=1234567890-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com \
  hello-world
Successfully started instance runbatch-38408320. To tail batch logs run:
CLOUDSDK_PYTHON_SITEPACKAGES=1 gcloud beta --project=long-octane-350517
logging tail 'logName="projects/long-octane-350517/logs/runbatch" AND
resource.labels.instance_id="runbatch-38408320"' --format='get(text_payload)'
```

Answer (score 0):

GCP launched their new "[Batch](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/compute/new-batch-service-processes-batch-jobs-on-google-cloud)" service in July '22. It basically Compute Engine packaged with some utilities to easily productionize a batch job -- including defining required resources, executables (script or container-based), and define a run schedule.

Haven't used it yet, but seems like a great fit for batch jobs that take over 1 hr.