# Is there a simple way to shutdown (or delete) a compute instance once its job is done?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am creating spot compute instances with `gcloud compute instances create-with-container` and I want to delete them once containers are done.

I found two solutions so far and they are not satisfactory:

1. Give them a startup-script with auto shutdown at the end. I thought the point of create-with-container was I can just launch the container without setting things up. I move to `create` from `create-with-container` to deal with fewer setups.
2. Call shutdown inside a container at the end of its job. The problem is when the container encounters an error it fails to call shutdown.

Are there better and more robust ways of shutting down an instance when it finishes its job?

Comment: Test for error conditions before calling the compute instance.

Comment: try to check this [How to make GCE instance stop when its deployed container finishes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52748332/how-to-make-gce-instance-stop-when-its-deployed-container-finishes?rq=1) if this resolves your issue.